# Arrived after planned arrival date?

Tags: visas, uk

In my visa application I stated that I planned to arrive in the UK on 1st September, but me and my family now want to enter the UK on 13th September. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Nope, that's not a problem

Comment: Are *you* still entering the UK on September 1st and is your family coming on another flight? Or are you all together?